# .htaccess problems PHP directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I tried this morning to hide the .php extension in the URL and I found on the internet that I could edit the .htaccess file. So I created the .htaccess file in my 'localhost/Myproject/fr/' directory and since this moment, When I want to go to 'localhost/Myproject/fr/' it returns on the page :

```
'403 Forbidden , You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) PHP/7.3.21 Server at localhost Port 80'
```

I deleted the .htaccess file but it changed nothing... I also tried to re install WAMP but it's still the same. Can someone know how to fix this problem please ? I still can access the others directory in my projets like 'localhost/Myproject/en/'.

To sum up : I don't have the .htaccess file anymore but the problem is still there...

Here is the code of the .htaccess I found on the internet before I deleted the file :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://localhost/site/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/site/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.site.com
RewriteRule (.*) http:// site.com$1 [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/site/erreur
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not simply getting fooled by your browser cache here?

Comment: Clear your browser's cache!